# Not able to generate shared key while creating password vault jboss eap 6

Tags: jboss6.x

I have created a password vault using java jdk 1.8 keytool.
The keystore is created

```
Please enter a Digit::  0: Store a secured attribute  1: Check whether a secured attribute exists  2: Remove secured attribute  3: Exit 0
Task: Store a secured attribute
Please enter secured attribute value (such as password):
Please enter secured attribute value (such as password) again:
Values match
Enter Vault Block:ds_Example
Enter Attribute Name:ds_password
Secured attribute value has been stored in vault.
Please make note of the following:
********************************************
Vault Block:ds_Example
Attribute Name:ds_password
Configuration should be done as follows:
VAULT::ds_Example::ds_password::1
********************************************
```

It doesn't generate the shared key.Please help

Comment: See the doc: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.1/html/Security_Guide/Configure_the_Enterprise_Application_Platform_to_Use_the_Password_Vault1.html

Comment: Referred that one only. 
I have used this command to create vault :

keytool -genseckey -alias vault -storetype jceks -keyalg AES -keysize
128 -storepass vault22 -keypass vault22 -validity 730 -keystore C:/vault/vault.keystore